# Do I have to explicitly declare ports if I've defined an interface?

Tags: juju

Do I have to do open_port 80 in my install hook if I declare my app to be `http`, or will `juju expose` do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

All port openings need to be explicit. In an example like `http` port 80 isn't the only port an http server could run on.

#### Docs:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-exposing
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/reference-hook-tools#open-port